# Angular Service Worker disabled in nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular14

I am building a Angular14 Progressive Web App (PWA) with service worker by following [these guide](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started).

The `ServiceWorkerModule` is importet in `app.module.ts` with this code:

```js
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
    enabled: true,
    registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
})
```

If I hoste my Angular application with:

```
ng build
http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/dw-frontend
```

in chrome i can see that service workers are active and running (by chrome dev tools > App > Service Workers).

If I hoste the same application in a Docker container with **nginx**, it seems that the service workers are disabled. I can't figure out why they are activated in the first case and not with the same code in the second case.

Her is my nginx configuration file:

```
events{}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I found out now, the problem had nothing to do with nginx or docker at all. I installed the Angular application on my Docker server outside my home network while testing with the http-server under localhost. As it turns out, outside of localhost for service worker you need **a valid SSL connection**, which I didn't have. After installing an SSL certificate it now works.